# New top bar doesn't show hot threads across Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, top-bar

Before today, I would visit Stack Overflow every day and click somewhere in the upper-left corner (I've forgotten what it said, and it's gone now!) and if I didn't have any notifications I would see a list of interesting questions from various sites in the Stack Exchange network which - I believe - were classified as "hot".

Now this new top bar has appeared, and I have no idea how to get this list any more. I'm not really sure what it was called so my searches have been useless as well.

Comment: The whole menu has been revamped. Hot questions have moved to the front page, right-hand side (scroll down a little).

Comment: I only see 12 questions there... I'm pretty sure there were at least twice that many before.

Comment: yes, the ability to get hot questions on a particular site is useful too. looks like getting it cross-site may not be implemented yet.

Comment: I meant to say: And there is always http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hot questions are now in the sidebar on the front page of each site. Full list of all 100 hot questions can be found on [Stack Exchange portal](https://stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to get more than 12 questions to show?  I seem to recall there being at least twice that many before...

Comment: @Michael Perhaps you're thinking of the [entire network's hot question list](http://stackexchange.com/questions) rather than the per site hot question list.

Comment: Yes, that is *exactly* what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You mean these ?

They just moved to the side of the main page. I like it better there but that's my opinion.

> [image]

Comment: So, is Spivak cheating? ;)