# Where do high view counts come from?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, views, sidebar

On a couple of the Stack Exchange network sites in which I regularly participate, there will frequently be a new question (less than an hour old) with views reaching 1k, 2k, or even more.  Normally there would be only a handful of views - say 10 to 15.

Is someone gaming the system or are some questions actually showing up in a Google search and magically receiving a lot of interest?  I do not believe an arcane question in English Language Learners would generate that kind of interest.

I can't believe that there is any kind of bug in the view count system.

Apparently the answer to this question is that some questions "get hot" and in [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756) there is much discussion about how "hotness" is determined.

This is simply a question about the apparent effects of that hotness (where do the views come from), not a question about the complex thermodynamics of stack exchange questions.

**Two days later:**

Today I had a not especially wildly interesting [question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/is-a-climbing-cut-on-a-table-saw-ever-justified) "arbitrarily" or "randomly" (take your pick) showed up on the list of hot questions. Lots of views, but few, if any, stray up votes for the question. Still, what a rush!  And I wasn't late for the party.

Comment: I'd be interested in an example.

Comment: Probably hot network questions. Here's a recent one from that site http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61701/why-is-the-adjective-for-mutate-not-mutatable

Comment: This has been around for 14 hours, not the one hour I mentioned, but it still stands out for a high view count (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61701/why-is-the-adjective-for-mutate-not-mutatable)

Comment: Can you link us the question that got 1k views in 1 hour? That's extremely rare. While it's not uncommon for something to get 1k views in 1 hour, it's rare for it to happen during the *first* hour. It usually takes time for stuff to get traction on Reddit or Hacker News.

Comment: Just google the question title with quotes around it.  You'll find hits to SO, superuser, serverfault, askubuntu, etcetera.  In other words, the Hot Question List.

Comment: We get this on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) all the time. the difference between [17 views](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/what-are-the-criteria-for-tent-for-one-person) and [8K views](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/679/can-i-shoot-a-bear-in-self-defense) is the hot network questions. It's a good way for us to grow our site. We'd like to get more on the side bar if we could TBH...

Comment: Visit [Aviation.SE] for hot view counts!

Comment: related: [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The one you picked out is currently on the [hot network questions](https://stackexchange.com/?page=1) list shown in rotation on the side bar on all sites.

So it is expected that this will garner more traffic than the norm.

Comment: Good point, I'll check that list next time I see inexplicable 1k or 2k views.

Comment: @ASTPace Won't help you much if you are too late for the party. Another tip, check the revision-history whether the question was publicized over twitter or suchlike.

Comment: @Deduplicator You have correctly surmised that I am the kind of person who is late for the party, frequently bearing no gift.

Comment: Also many times questions are shared via sites like reddit, causing lots of traffic, and it's not recorded anywhere in Stack Exchange.