# Why are there so many questions about simple real life talks?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I've noticed for a long time already, that <strike>almost all</strike> some Hot Questions in some communities (Academia, Workplace, RPG, etc.) can all be answered without digging, with the same answer:

> Go and talk to whomever you have a problem with!

I have checked some of those questions - and the most sensible (and the most highly-voted) answers were exactly about social communication - as expected.

IMHO, it's the same kind of question that can be answered, like: "Google it.", "Read the Wikipedia", etc. - put it simply, the OP does nothing to answer their own question.

Are those questions really helpful in any way to anyone, except inspirating the OP? Shouldn't they be closed?

Comment: They should be closed as 'social'.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)

Comment: Future possible questions in the "Hot network questions" : "How to breathe?", "How to type an `a`?", etc.

Comment: As a matter of fact we have [an individual close reason](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1741/7734) for such questions on Academia.

Answer (score 6):

Hot Questions List is optimized for [bikeshedding questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality). Many of those are indeed closed, and hence are not present on the list. The ones you see may well have 3-4 votes to close already, or are currently in the "reopen" part of close-reopen tug-of-war. Sometimes, the author manages to state the question to just barely avoid closevotes.

If you scan thousands of questions across hundreds of sites looking for those that are most trivial or discussion-y but are not closed (yet?), you are bound to find *something*.

Comment: Not a good example, but anyway - what about this one: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54840/can-i-prevent-my-company-from-modifying-source-code-that-i-wrote-for-myself-and - it has a plenty of upvotes and a massively upvoted accepted answer which states among other explanations: `... You can just say it ...`. It doesn't seem to me that this question is going to be closed soon.

Comment: It's a genuine question, if simple. "Easy to answer" is not a reason to close.   An answer containing the words "You can just say it" _among other things_ is not necessarily bad. As for upvotes: it's about a programmer's experience,  SO users can sympathize with that.

Comment: I'm trying not to abstract the things. The question contains 2 parts: the legal one, and the social one. I guess that OP is coming for the second one, since he asks in the Workplace community: `How can I say to them that I didn't like it, without being rude?`. It's obvious that only the OP knows details about his colleagues, managers, company, habits, etc. With that much information provided in his question the only reasonable answer would be: `Go and try to ask not being rude` - and there it is. I see absolutely no help to any other person from this question and this answer.

Comment: Take it to [meta.workplace.se]

Comment: I'd like to, but this kind of question comes from multiple communities, so I decided to ask on the global meta.

Comment: @abyss.7 you can take some examples from Programmers, to make it multi-site question: [Recent Trouble With Popularity](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7525/31260)