# Is Stack Exchange becoming more focused on funny or entertaining content rather than actual useful information?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, trolling

It feels like Stack Exchange has basically turned into Reddit in a way. With a lot of SEs like Workplace.SE, Academia.SE, IPS.SE, Worldbuilding.SE, etc.

These SEs are used mostly to kill time/read entertaining things rather than actually get answers. If you look at the popular questions on some of these they are completely indistinguishable from trolling.

For example there's one on Workplace.SE right now where a guy talks about someone eating 75 McDonalds hamburgers. I mean come on - it's obviously a troll question but even if it was real what useful information is this providing to anyone? This question is not at all unique either.

A lot of these questions seem to be pretty far from the mission of SE which is expert answers to questions. They seem to be more like Reddit, just to kill time.

Is SE becoming like Reddit?

Note: My point isn't about whether or not the question was a troll. More specifically my point is that the reason for those questions to become popular seems to be that people are viewing/upvoting them because they're funny or entertaining, NOT because they believe there's some useful information coming from it.

Comment: If you have an issue with a question asked at [workplace.se] then I think you should raise it on their Meta rather than here.

Comment: @PolyGeo My question here has almost literally nothing to do with that question

Comment: I think we're safe as long as nobody is hanging out 
baconing narwhals or whatever fresh perversions those redditors are up to these days.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think Reddit is bad, I use Reddit too. I just don't think SE was meant to be like Reddit

Comment: Well, it's sorta meant to be like Digg, which Reddit was also sorta meant to be like. So, think of it as divergent evolution: Stack Overflow covers these topics with Q&A, Reddit covers them with memes.

Comment: related: [Recent string of trolling questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4839/168) and [What's the story with this user](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4410/168) at Workplace meta. TL;DR: exploiting hot questions by trolling is a long known issue, sites impacted by it suffer a lot but Stack Exchange management doesn't give a sh!t, possibly because this helps to entertain Stack Overflow users who bring tens thousands clicks a day

Comment: Seems that you fell for the bait...

Comment: Perhaps the OP use of hyperbole  was a bit exaggerated, but what he surely mean was "he ate *a lot* of burgers*"... if he is trolling or not, the Workplace-related situation still applies, and is about how/if a manager should handle that situation (something useful), and also got several non-troll and useful answers that many users can benefit from (disclaimer: I am top answerer on that Q)

Comment: @DarkCygnus My point isn't the number of burgers - it's that the question reads like a bad soap opera.

Comment: Please give link to hamburger question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reddit is one site split up into many categories. SE's kind of many sites on a common platform.

As hard as it may be to accept - not all problems that need solving are technical. I mean, sure, you can stick to sites like SO or Super User, with a strictly technical bend, or sites that extend the QA format to still primarily objective answers, like seasoned advice.

There's some sites that just seem oddly shaped for us. I've thought that religion sites (with the exception of judaism) were an odd fit for SE - but they've often proven to be useful if not occasionally controversial, and subjective sites.

And well, no one has perfect experience on subjective issues. The first inkling I got that a job I had just been hired on wasn't going to work out was through a workplace (and while I use my sock account for that, I've actually gotten good advice.)

Sure there's a few trolls milking HNQ - but sites like Academia, IPS and Workplace *do* actually provide useful advice, when used properly (and common sense applied to answers and questions!)

Worldbuilding is *odd* until you realise that many of SE's core userbase - whether they be developers or not are geeks (or nerds. Take your pick). While its a topic with no correct answers, or practical consideration, its useful for folks who want to write fiction, or alt history.

In a sense, all these sites have value, within the QA format, for the *people* who use it. *Unlike* reddit, mods and users have some, direct investment in quality, and the community can manage itself to an extent.

If you see something that doesn't belong? Work out the community's views on it and flag, or if you're a more experienced user, VTC. You're our first line of defense against redditness ;)

Answer (score 19):

In all seriousness, there *do* actually exist subreddits where people exchange useful information about things that matter.

They're brutally difficult to *find*, but now and then I will stumble into one in much the way that one stumbles into a magical forest glen. I pause, jaw dropping in amazement and greedily soak up as much knowledge as I am able to before I must blink and find it all gone and myself alone on a rotting log in a muddy ditch deep within the darkening woods...

...Then the wolves come.

Point is, Reddit doesn't *have* to be terrible and pointless, it just mostly *is* - particularly the bits that they make easy to find. Our goal here is to make places where folks can trade information on similar topics *without* being terrible and pointless about it. And also without accomplishing that by hiding it all away.

Now, anyone here can tell you: it doesn't always work. Any time you get more than 0 people together in a group, it's pretty much guaranteed that at least one of those people is going to be terrible *at least* some of the time. Catch any one of us at the wrong moment, and see the facade drop - it'll scar you some.

But we try our best to pick up the pieces of our shattered psyche and move on. Preferably closing and deleting copious numbers of terribleness on the way out. There's something at the core of the system here that is markedly different from what Reddit provides: [the empowerment of the core community to make substantive and lasting improvement to what is written here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). From flagging to closing, editing to deletion, the most critical tools are accessible to anyone able to demonstrate competence: no moderator caste needed. It doesn't always come easily, but at the end of the day it's the privilege and responsibility of *every* member of a site to make it something that they can be proud of.

Comment: tl;dr the system works the way it's intended, any _real_ problems with the system should be raised in the appropriate meta.

Comment: @Möoz system asked about here is *intended to entertain*, see [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773) Its primary target audience are Stack Overflow users and it's somewhat a big business: sampled clicks data that was a while ago posted in Tavern chat suggests that HNQ sidebar brings about 100K clicks a day, with something like 70% of these clicks coming from SO

Answer (score 7):

I am new to both StackExchange and Reddit.

From my experiences so far, Reddit runs like Twitter (a social-media site for sharing links, updates, and exchanging information), whereas StackExchange is much more narrowly focused on (intelligent) questions and answers (without the excessive spam found in Yahoo! Answers).

I would say that "Can someone eat 75 hamburgers?" is an intelligent question that can be answered professionally by a biologist or a nutritionist (though it would perhaps be better phrased as "What is the maximum number of hamburgers a person can eat?" which could probably be answered by checking the /Guinness Book of World Records/).

So I would say that overall no, ultimately they have very different goals in mind, and it would be pretty much impossible for StackExchange to become like Reddit.

Comment: Wow.  Okay.  I was curious so I did a Google Search, and it looks like it is actually possible for someone to eat 103 hamburgers in 8 minutes.  :-O

Answer (score 3):

Sites like Puzzling and Worldbuilding are largely focused around entertainment value rather than usefulness (or those two at least provide a *different kind* of usefulness).

This is not something I really have a problem with (except that it might set a bad precedent for other sites, but that's a different discussion).

The problem comes in when people try to use more serious sites like Workplace or Interpersonal Skills for entertainment.

Then you have people, like myself, who want to help others with their actual real-world broadly-applicable problems faced with a bunch of questions that are clearly made up purely for entertainment value.

In the short term, allowing the occasional such question isn't really a problem - it won't really hurt the useful questions.

In the long term, however:

- The specific site (and maybe the network as a whole) becomes more known for being less serious, which will significantly increase the number of such questions and make people with serious questions less likely to want to post something to there.
- This is made worse by Hot Network Questions, where the click-bait questions tend to go, meaning others on the network see a large percentage of non-serious questions from the site, making them think the site is a lot less serious than it generally is.
- Trolls also ask non-serious questions specifically with the aim to get to HNQ, which certainly doesn't help matters.
- The answers and comments would also likely become less serious over time, further reducing the real-world-problem-solving usefulness of the site (or at least the fight to keep them serious would become harder).
- People who provide serious answers and go out of their way to try to keep the site useful will be less inclined to keep doing that.

The question is then how we can actually deal with this.